# Encryption and decryption does not match in crypto-js

Tags: typescript, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to write function which encrypt and decrypt a text with given generated key and IV.

```
    export const encryptDataUsingKey = (
          text: string, // Hex
          key: string, // base64 (scrypt generated key)
          iv: string, // base64 (random 16 byte iv)
        ): string => {
          console.log({ key });
          console.log({ iv });
          console.log('encrypt.....');
          console.log({ text });
          const encryptedCipher = AES.encrypt(
            enc.Hex.parse(text),
            enc.Base64.parse(key),
            {
              iv: enc.Base64.parse(iv),
              padding: pad.NoPadding,
              mode: mode.CBC,
            },
          );
          console.log({ encryptedCipherText: encryptedCipher.toString() });
          console.log('decrypt.....');
          console.log({
            decryptedText: enc.Hex.stringify(
              AES.decrypt(encryptedCipher, enc.Base64.parse(key), {
                iv: enc.Base64.parse(iv),
                padding: pad.NoPadding,
                mode: mode.CBC,
              }),
            ),
          });
          return enc.Base64.stringify(encryptedCipher.ciphertext);
 };
```

But the text after encrypt and decrypt does not match with original value.

I am using NoPadding with CBC AES encryption.

OutPut of the upper code

```
Encrypted text
{key: "lqxEbMszL2FOsEaKI9eS0k8eC7vOwKq5D12wOeo43Rs="}
{iv: "1pX+XeDWJ0OXPnw6ePo9zw=="}
encrypt.....
{text: "0x7361776169"}
{encryptedCipherText: "JFnZRS3M"}
decrypt.....
{decryptedText: "fbf403de0a09"}
```

Comment: Change the padding to `pad.Pkcs7` and apply the plaintext without prefix `0x`.

Comment: so removing 0x works but not in case of NoPadding. can you tell me how can i use no padding since java have pkcs5 and js have pkcs7. only common options of padding was NoPadding.

Comment: You cannot select `NoPadding` for your plaintext with CBC! For CBC the plaintext must be an integer multiple of the blocksize (16 bytes for AES), which does not apply to your plaintext with a length of 5 bytes. Note that PKCS#7 padding is called PKCS#5 padding in the Java world (for historical reasons).